# Opening a terminal with a terminal - Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I just need the command for opening a new terminal in a terminal and then being able to identify that terminal and then run some java code in that terminal.

Comment: Terminal terminal terminal? Terminal! You could try "open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app"

Comment: You could use a multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`

Comment: First i don't know what a multiplexer is.  Secondly ik how to open a terminal dho thank you very much.  That isn't my question.

Comment: Why is my question marked down?  Also can you guys explain how i can make the current terminal visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to type this into a Terminal window, or put it in a script:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "/bin/date"'
```

Change `/bin/date` to your Java thing.

Comment: So i need to run an sh file which then compiles and run my java code.  Do i put sh file name in that spot?

Comment: Yes - try it! Try `date` first and then replace `date` with your `sh` file.

Comment: Like right now it runs basher in wrong directory so can i do multiple commands ex (cd desktop/"text editor")

Comment: Sure, just do `do script "command1; command2; command3"` or if `command2` must only happen if `command1` was successful, do `do script "command1 && command2"`

Comment: Wait why use apple script, or open a new window? Why not use the same one?

Comment: @prodigitalson I was merely answering the request for a new window - I too would use the existing window.

Comment: Because the original is never visible.  Thanks

Comment: @MarkSetchell Wasnt criticizing your answer... was criticizing the question/approach :-)

Comment: If i am using the system function with a specified terminal can I open that specific terminal if not already open.  How would you do it with same terminal like u said above.  (edit) I understand what you are saying now.  It would be logical to use the same terminal because its at the right path just don't know how to make it visible

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand what you are asking now.

Comment: When I use system() i am sending things to the terminal.  I want to open the terminal that i am currently using.  If i write a cmd to open a terminal window (aka the above) it is a new window at a different path (computer instead of desktop/correct folder)